# Adding an attribute to an IdentityUser default property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 in an MVC 5 solution and I extended the default IdentityUser entity with some custom properties.

Now I was wondering whether there's a way to add some attributes to the existing default properties. Specifically I'd like to add a [Display] attribute to PhoneNumber and UserName properties.
I know I should map my model entity to a viewmodel one and have the display attribute on it, but sometimes I'm lazy :)

Thanks

Comment: What is the benefit of not creating a ViewModel? I would advise you not to use your domain models in views.

Comment: Yes, I know, I use them in most of the views, but I want to use the domain models in some index views where I only show a list of user.

Comment: I know this is not what you want to hear but I would avoid that. You should try and keep your domain entities and your View Models completely separate and abstract them as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a metadata class to IdentityUser entity

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public class User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin,UserRole, UserClaim>, IEntity
{        
     public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager)
     {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
     }
}

public class UserMetaData
{
     [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
     public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

**NOTE: I agree with the comments above that you should not to use your Entitiy Models in views and use ViewModels.**